# Android Video Encoding

Tags: android, video-encoding

I just want to merge a mp3 file and image file into mp4 video format. I have done google on this topic and found some third parties libraries such as FFMPEG,Jcodec etc and i am unable to use these libraries. So please help me out from this problem.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent tried this on Android. But on PC you can use this to create the mp4 file using ffmpeg

The following worked for me

ffmpeg -i download.jpg -r 1/100 -i test.mp3 -s 720x480 out.mp4

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

[ffmpeg images-to-video script anyone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468274/ffmpeg-images-to-video-script-anyone)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..on window i also done this...but for this time i need this for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the FFmpeg ported for android:

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

you can call commands via JNI wrapper.